# Combining arraylists of different object types into one

Tags: java, swing, object, arraylist, awt

I have some arraylists which contain objects (for a paint like program) based on a constructor in a class, and wish to put them all in the same arraylist rather so each item redraws in order.

ive tried to turn the array into a 2d array (unsuccessfully) and also tried attaching an identifier to each object and printing to the console what I get back from the base array which is `package1.package2.ShapeClas@<string of letters and numbers>`unsuccessfully getting returns i can do anything with.

The arrays in question I wish to combine are similar to below

```
public static ArrayList<ShapeClass> emptyRectangle = new ArrayList<ShapeClass>();
public static ArrayList<ShapeClass> filledRectangles = new ArrayList<ShapeClass>();
public static ArrayList<ShapeClass> lineArray = new ArrayList<ShapeClass>();
```

With each array being populated by objects created along the lines of (with a few other things helping which can share if this is not enough), the scale of the shapes change with the size of the windows on rescaling

```
for (ShapeClass cr : emptyRectangle) {
            g.setColor(cr.getForeground());
            Rectangle2D r = cr.getRectangle();
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.draw(new Rectangle2D.Double(r.getX() * JPanel1.getWidth(), r.getY() 
                    * JPanel1.getHeight(),r.getWidth() * JPanel1.getWidth(), 
                    r.getHeight() * JPanel1.getHeight()));
        }
```

I wish to be able to combine the arrays into one so I can redraw each element in order, as it stands now they are drawn by shape type, and so one shape type always overlaps the other. How would I get these into a singular array and successfully identify which shape to draw?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [`List.addAll'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll(java.util.Collection))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the ArrayList class implements the List interface, you can do so simply by using the `.addAll(Collection c)` method from the List interface easily.

```
ArrayList<ShapeClass> allShape = new ArrayList<>();    
allShape.addAll(emptyRectangle);
allShape.addAll(filledRectangles);
allShape.addAll(lineArray);
```

**Edit:**

**Approach 1:** You do not have access to the ShapeClass

When an object is added to a Collection (of widening generic type), the actual class the object will not be changed. You can get back its class using the .getClass() method. However, it has to be cast back to its original form before its method can be called.

```
    for(ShapeClass shape: allShapes) {
        System.out.println(shape.getClass()); // class <actual class>
        if(shape instanceof Triangle) {
            Triangle tri = (Triangle) shape;
            tri.paint();
        } else if(shape instanceof Rectangle) {
            Rectangle rec = (Rectangle) shape;
            rec.paint();
        }
    }
```

**Approach 2 (better)**: You have access to the ShapeClass (dynamic binding)

It would be easier to achieve the same purpose if you have access to the Generic Class (i.e. ShapeClass). In this case, you only have to define a method `paint()` in the `ShapeClass`, and override it in the subclass (e.g. Rectangle).

**Method call is dynamically binded in Java. So the JVM will check the actual type and call the most concrete method for you**

```
    ArrayList<ShapeClass> allShape = new ArrayList<>();
    allShape.addAll(emptyRectangle);
    allShape.addAll(filledRectangles);
    allShape.addAll(lineArray);

    for(ShapeClass shape: allShape) {
        shape.paint();   // make sure you have a paint() method in the ShapeClass, and it is overriden in the subclass. 
    }
```

Comment: yes but when I wish to repaint them, I have no idea how to instigate the right method because each shape needs its own method to be drawn properly, as the shapes use different calls, and I cant use those different calls without identifying the shape, but no idea how to attach that identification (tried a 2d array which has an itentifying property then the shape values, but woudlnt work)

Comment: @Anan I edited my answer to show how you can identify the shape and call their own method to draw. Hope this helps.